# CSRFGuard Javascript Injection doesn't work

Tags: javascript, csrf, code-injection

What am I doing wrong?  I can't get the javascript injection to work.  Here is what I put in my web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>Owasp.CsrfGuard.Config</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/csrfguard.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>Owasp.CsrfGuard.Config.Print</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>CSRFGuard</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CSRFGuard</filter-name> 
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JavaScriptServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.owasp.csrfguard.servlet.JavaScriptServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JavaScriptServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/JavaScriptServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In my jsp files, I add this line:

```
<script src="/JavaScriptServlet"></script>
```

But when I submit, the token doesn't get added to the request.  I stepped through the code, and this line in CsrfGuard.verifySessionToken(request) returns null:

```
String tokenFromRequest = request.getParameter(getTokenName());
```

The only thing I can do so far is to add the token by using the CSRF custom tag and adding a hidden field to the form ala:

```
<input type="hidden" name="<csrf:tokenname/>" value="<csrf:tokenvalue/>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I had to figure out what my servlet context root was first.  Then I fixed it by changing

```
<script src="/JavaScriptServlet"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="/[servletcontextroot]/JavaScriptServlet"></script>
```

Comment: Even when you change to /[servletcontextroot]/JavaScriptServlet" it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it worked fine when I added the script tag after the base path was set.